# NSDictionary inside a private NSArray gets deallocated outside the scope of viewDidLoad

Tags: nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a bizarre situation here. I have a private NSArray holding an  NSDictionary of my data. As soon as I move outside the scope of viewDidLoad (i.e into the scope of another method), the NSDictionary gets automatically deallocated and the app crashes with "message sent to deallocated instance." Declaring the NSArray as a strong property didn't resolve the issue. How can I make the NSArray retain its objects?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I figured I did not actually own the dictionary contained inside of my array, hence it being deallocated outside of the scope of viewDidLoad.

This is a must-read for any mid-level iOS developer:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.pdf